# Customizing Identity for .NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to customize Identity and I'm getting the following error when trying to have my DbContextClass inherit from IdentityUser:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0311  The type 'CustomerManager.Domain.User' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'CustomerManager.Domain.User' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUser'. CustomerManager.Data    E:\Clients\DMFA\CustomerManager\CustomerManager.Data\CustomerManagerContext.cs  9   Active

**User Class:**

```
public class User : IdentityUser<long, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastNme { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext Class:**

```
public class CustomerManagerContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public CustomerManagerContext(DbContextOptions<CustomerManagerContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

**UserLogin Class:**

```
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<long>
{
}
```

**UserRole Class:**

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
{
}
```

**UserClaim Class:**

```
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<long>
{
}
```

Despite what I think to be correct I get the above error in my DbContext Class.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Why does your `IdentityUser` have all of the `<long, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>` properties on it? I don't think you need all of that.

Comment: @NovaDev see PankajKapare answer

Comment: you may want to start simpler and then work your way to more complexity. The answer below that you pointed to doesn't answer the question about why you want add those properties in that fashion...

Comment: @NovaDev you are absolutely right. answer the question to claim your credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to start simpler and then work your way to more complexity. I hope this helps!

```
public class User : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastNme { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have customized User and Role Your CustomerManagementContext definition should look like below.

```
public class CustomerManagementContext  : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<long>, long, UserLogin,UserRole,UserClaim>{}
```

Comment: After the changes it still says the User class is not convertible to an IdentityUser.